# distance between two points in a image in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I want to find the distance between the two points in the image as shown

[image: distance]

I found it by taking  the coordinates by using ginput which was a manual selection method. Now I need another method to find the distance between them.

Does anyone have any suggestion for me?

Comment: I assume you're not asking not for a way to get distance between two known coordinates- but rather for a way to get those coordinates off the image using something that doesn't require you to manually select points (like ginput). If this is the case, can you elaborate on why you selected those particular coordinates so that someone can help you write something that will return your desired coordinates and the distance between them automatically?

Comment: Basically,I need to find the distance between the  two far apart holes in the whole image either in vertical axis or in horizontal axis.I thought these are two far apart holes in the image and marked the line like that.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a Laplacian of a Gaussian convolution to detect blops at different scales (if these circles will always be of same size you can fine-tune your algorithm to only detect this exact size). See e.g. here: http://code.google.com/p/blobdetector/ (or just google "matlab blop detection")

Of course, you will probably face a lot more problems when trying to robustly implement this, but this can at least get you started.

**EDIT** Seems like you are really just searching for a way to compute the distance between two points. According to Pythagoras this is, given points p1 and p2:

```
sqrt((p1(1) - p2(1))^2 + (p1(2) - p2(2))^2)
```

Or in your case using `ginput`:

```
p = ginput(2);
sqrt(sum((p(:,1) - p(:,2)).^2))
```

Comment: Thanks but I think there is no need to detect the blobs (or holes) in the image which are constant but just need to calculate the distance between the two far apart holes.   If you have any idea to find the distance between two far part holes please suggest so that I can start right now!!

Comment: Yes, you gave the right solution which I used previously in the same way with ginput .But I need to calculate the distance between two far apart holes in the image automatically not by using the manual methods like ginput.

Comment: So you want to manually detect where a mouse click occured? Sorry, your intentions are still unclear.

Comment: No..I need an algorithm that will automatically yields the distance between two far apart holes in the image when the image shown above is fed as an input image.

Comment: But still you think you do not need to detect the holes? That means they are constant? which means the visibilty of the holes changes or what?

Comment: Tobold thanks for your response...But my main task is to find the distance between the two holes without manually getting the coordinates of holes(circles/blobs) in the image.The image itself a constant which makes implies that the holes are also constant.So,I need to write an matlab algorithm that will detect the distance between two far part holes in the image!!!!!